Ubuntu VM running on HyperV in Windows 10 machine remote desktopn has display and performance issues
I have an Ubuntu VM running in HyperV on a Windows 10 machine. When I connect to the VM using the HyperV viewer window everything looks and functions just fine except for the fact that the resolution is locked at 1024x768 as well as the fact that by default I am not able to copy/paste into and from the VM to the host Windows machine. I have previously set up a Fedora VM in HyperV and have been able to do everything I need to do by connecting to the VM using Remote Desktop by having xrdp being set up on the VM, so I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu VM the same way but am coming across an issue with the performance and the display of the VM.
Here's the setup:
Host Machine:

Windows 10 Enterprise version 22H2
OS Build 19045.5131
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0
HyperV manager version 10.0.19041.1

VM:

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel 6.8.0-49-generic
Desktop Environment: Gnome 46.0
Shell: Bach 5.2.21
Window Manger: Mutter
Windows Manager Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
xrdp version 0.9.24

The main issue is that when I connect to the VM using Remote Desktop the display is very different and the performance is very slow (applications take quite a while to open, internet is slow, etc).
For clarification, here's a screenshot of what it looks like when using the HyperV viewer (desktop displays with default settings, surrounding black area is due to small resolution):

and here's a screenshot of what I see when connecting to the VM via Remote Desktop (desktop is just blue, this shot is the view after pressing the command button to illustrate that the desktop is just blue):

When I run neofetch, the only things that are different from running it in the session via Remote Desktop is that the resolution is different as well as the values listed for the memory. In the spirit of being thorough, here are screenshots of both of them:
Remote Desktop

HyperV

another thing I've found is that the output from running xrandr displays differently between the two
Remote Desktop:

HyperV:

I know that I can personalize the desktop appearance for the Remote Desktop instance, but the fact that by default it looks different from how it looks when booted up from the HyperV along with the fact that the performance is worse leads me to believe that there is something not configured properly to allow Remote Desktop session to look and behave just like the HyperV session when the VM is booted.
If there is anytihng that is not clear or if there's any extra data I need to provide to help with troubleshooting. Thanks!
